# Is it possible to make a spring gateway route case insensitive?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to make a predicate path of a spring gateway route case insensitive.  For example, if I want to go to localhost:8888/gEt/UsErit should match my path of /get/user.

Haven't been able to find anything to make a path case insensitive.

```
spring:
   cloud:
      gateway:
         - id: user
           uri: localhost:8000
           predicates:
              -Path=/get/user
```

I expect to be able to route from localhost:8888/gEt/UsEr to localhost:8000 but don't know if there is a way to remove case sensitivity from paths.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is not possible to do.  please look at the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#path-route-predicate-factory)

Path doesn't accept regexp. But regexp can be used for queryparams, cookies and for others.

But you can specify multiple paths like this.

```
spring:
   cloud:
      gateway:
         - id: user
           uri: localhost:8000
           predicates:
              -Path=/get/user, /Get/User, ......
```

Also if you look at the `PredicateSpec` class, you can see that there are only two variations

```
public BooleanSpec path(String... patterns) {
   ....
}

public BooleanSpec path(boolean matchOptionalTrailingSeparator, String... patterns) {
   .....
}
```

Comment: I checked the documentation but I did see this post (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17876) where you can turn off case insensitivity if you route through java, and not a config file.

Comment: but this has nothing to do with spring gateway as such. This is adapting the requestmapping to accept strings without being sensitive to case. Your question was if its possible to do in spring gateway configuration while routing the requet, which you cannot.